# How did Cull Obsidian's hand grow back in the battle of Wakanda?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In the fight scene near the Sanctum Santorum in *Avengers: Infinity War* Cull Obsidian's hand got cut off by a closing portal, but in the battle of Wakanda it was grown back to normal.

Does he have Regeneration power?

Comment: Cross-post: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193684/does-cull-obsidian-have-limb-regeneration

Comment: I think a weapon was attached to his severed arm.

Answer (score 12):

No, he doesn't have regeneration power.

He got an artificial arm like Bucky and Luke Skywalker.

**Before:**

[image]

[image: Cull Obsidian reaching through a portal]

**After:**

[image: Cull Obsidian's prosthetic arm next to Proxima Midnight]

[image]

Since Thanos has been replacing Nebula's body parts with machines, we know he is quite capable at doing cybernetic enhancements.